# Return JSON using List<> Object Nested Element Formatting On Result

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, c#-4.0

My list object is a linear rows of data of which I pull from the dbcontext identity model. The issue is the JSON structure needs to be returned with the value wrapped in a nested parameter. See example. How do I achieve this? The data in the child does not need to be a separate model class defined as the data just need to be defined a certain way in the results to the accepting javascript client library.

Code Below Returns From JSON Result of controller.

```
using (var dc = new EntitiesDB.CalendarEntities())
{
  var evt1 = (from e in dc.CalendarEvents(startDate, endDate)
             select new
              {
                 e.EventID,
                 e.Subject,
                 e.startDateRecur,
                 e.startTimeRecur,
         e.Ruletype,
         e.RuleValue                           
}).ToList();

   return Json(evt1.Select(v => new
   {
      id = v.EventID,
      title = v.Subject,
      startRecur = v.startDateRecur,                    
      startTime = v.startTimeRecur,
      ruleType = v.RuleType,
      ruleValue = v.RuleValue
   }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

```
[{
"id":222044,
"title":"Sample Day Recur Event 1",
"startRecur":"1/1/2019",                    
"startTime":"00:12:00",
"ruleType":"Weekly",
"ruleValue" = "True"
},
{
"id":222045,
"title":"Sample Day Recur Event 2",
"startRecur":"1/1/2019",                    
"startTime":"00:15:00",
"ruleType":"Weekly",
"ruleValue" = "True"
}]
```

**How do I make it return the result so I can put some of the values into a nested element "rrule" in the result like this?**

```
[{
"id":222044,
"title":"Sample Day Recur Event 1",
"startRecur":"1/1/2019",                    
"startTime":"00:12:00",
rrule: { 
         "ruleType":"Weekly",
         "ruleValue" = "True"
       }
},
{
"id":222045,
"title":"Sample Day Recur Event 2",
"startRecur":"1/1/2019",                    
"startTime":"00:15:00",
rrule: { 
         "ruleType":"Weekly",
         "ruleValue" = "True"
       }
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd project a new type for `rrule` using object initializer syntax like this:

```
return Json(evt1.Select(v => new
   {
      id = v.EventID,
      title = v.Subject,
      startRecur = v.startDateRecur,                    
      startTime = v.startTimeRecur,
      rrule = new { 
          ruleType = v.RuleType,
          ruleValue = v.RuleValue
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, Stuart, this was a case of overthinking it and being a new to the model classes in mvc :)  I appreciate the quick response.